# How to change database values with dynamically created buttons in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am dynamically creating html content with PHP and I am creating a button and when that button is clicked It should invoke a PHP script that will update the values of a column of a specific row in the database

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        header("Location: login.php");
    }else{
        require_once("mysqli_connect.php");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM markeri WHERE odobreno ='F'";

        $response = @mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

        if($response){
            echo "<hr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)){
                echo "<div align='center' id='markeri'><h3>Naziv: " . $row['naziv'] . "</h3>";
                echo "<h3>Ulica: " . $row['ulica'] . "</h3>";
                echo "<h3>Opis:</h3>" . "<p>" . $row['opis'] . "</p>";
                echo "<h4>Email: " . $row['email'] . "</h4>";
                echo "<img src='" . $row['link_slike'] . "' width='300px' /></br>";
                echo "<form action='update.php' method='POST'>";
                echo "<textarea rows='10' cols='30' maxlength='500' placeholder='Komentar' name='" . $row['marker_id'] . "'></textarea></br>";
                echo "<input type='button' value='Odobri' name='" . $row['marker_id'] . "b" . "' /></form><hr>";
            }
        }




    }


?>
```

I tried something like making the name of the textarea equal to the marker_id in my database and making the name of the button the value of marker_id + the string "b" but I don't know how to call them on my update.php script. Usually when it is a normal case and when there is no dynamic content I know how to do it with `$_POST['name'];`

**EDIT:**

I used AJAX to dynamically create the HTML as you told me but I've encountered another problem

```
<script>
    function page_loaded(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "get_data_dashboard.php",
            success: function(data){
                var markers = JSON.parse(data);
                for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
                    var m = markers[i];
                    var markerHTML = "<div class='marker'>" +
                        "<span id='naziv'>Naziv zahtjeva: " + m.naziv + "</span></br>" + 
                        "<span id='ulica'>Ulica: " + m.ulica + "</span></br>" + 
                        "<p id='opis'>Opis:</br>" + m.opis + "</p></br>" + 
                        "<span id='email'>Email: " + m.email + "</span></br>" + 
                        "<img id='slika' src='" + m.link_slike + "' />" + "</br>" + 
                        "<textarea rows='5' cols='30' maxlength='500' id='t" + m.marker_id + "' placeholder='Komentar'>" + "</textarea></br>"
                        + "<div class='buttons'><a href='odobri_prijavu.php?id=" + m.marker_id + "'>Odobri</a>" +
                            "<a href='izbrisi_prijavu.php?id=" + m.marker_id + "'>Izbriši</a>"  + "</div>"  + 
                        "</div><hr>";

                    $('#content').append(markerHTML);
                }

            }
        })



    }
    $(document).ready(page_loaded());

</script>
```

I tried to use buttons but I couldn't figure how to add event handlers to dynamically created buttons that will post a request via AJAX to some php script with the proper id as the value and the value of the textarea. So I used the anchor tag and I was able to send the id, but I can't send the value of the textarea because I don't know how to reference it and even if I referenced it, it will be NULL because its value is set to the anchor tag at the very beginning and I want to type in text in the textarea.

Comment: If i am understanding you correctly ,your php content is all ran before and of the clicks or javascript happens.. You will have to look into using ajax to change the content.

Comment: @happymacarts For every row in my database a new form is created like that one above and with a button. But how do I access the button so I can call an event on it with JavaScript and get the value of the textarea and then use AJAX ?

Comment: i would add a class in the php/html markup to it and create an event based on that class

Comment: also avoid using an ID for multiple items on the same page, use a css class instead

Comment: @happymacarts Could you show me an example of what you mean ? I don't understand you very well because I just started programming in PHP.

Comment: There may be a confusion about the term "dynamic" here. PHP runs server-side... Long before a user interaction or a client-side script (even if it is triggered onload) has ran. What's called "dynamic" in term of element creation is elements which weren't present on page load, due to various reasons. PHP has nothing to do in this, except being a ressource to update/create new elements, via ajax.

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: @happymacarts Yes

Comment: I guess i am not fully understanding what it is you are most having difficulty with. Creating the loop in php to generate your html form(s) or handling the form submit? What info do you need to pass to the update.php file?

Comment: @happymacarts I want to pass the whole $row to the update.php, so what I mean by that I want to pass all the columns of each row when the button is clicked($row['naziv'], $row['ulica'] etc.]). So I can update the content in the database.

Comment: That is where you're lost: *«... I want to pass all the columns of each row when the button is clicked...»* Again, PHP runs server-side and finished its job *looong* before the user can see it. At this point, you have to handle the data using client-side scripts (javascript, jQuery) in order to go back to the server-side for additional ressources, **Ajax is the keyword to search**. ;)

Comment: Thank you sir. I will try it :D

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".btn_class_nm").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://domain.com/phpscript_filenm.php",
         data: {
            val1:"val1",
            val2:"val1",
         },
          success: function(msg){
             alert( "record updated"); //Anything you want
          }
       });   


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all give a Class Name to the Button as it is being generated dynamically and the number of them can vary based on the number of records the query returns. Something like this:-

```
echo "<input type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-block active view_data'  value='Odobri' name='" . $row['marker_id'] . "b" . "' /></form><hr>";
```

Note that I have add view_data in the class definition. This will help is trapping the onclick event through jquery.

the jquery will be something like

```
$('.view_data').click(function(){   
    var yourvariable = JSON.stringify($(this).val()); //Gets Clicked button value   

 $.ajax({       
     url:"workstatus.php",          
         method:"post",         
         data:{yourvariable:yourvariable, anymoreyourvariables:anymoreyourvariables, ,  },          
         success:function(data){        
             $('#htmldivID').html(data);//If you want result there.
             alert( "record updated"); //Anything you want
         }          
 });
```

I hope this helps you.